# Would Scripts count as "pirated versions of copyright materials"?

Tags: discussion, copyright

I recently asked [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/27180/1587) on finding a database for translated Drama CD Scripts. one of the [comments by Logan M](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27180/is-there-a-database-for-translated-drama-cd-scripts?noredirect=1#comment37927_27180) was (emphasis mine)

> I am not aware of any English-language database of drama CDs at all, let alone one which includes translations (**which is possibly a violation of our policy not to answer questions requesting pirated versions of copyright materials anyway**, but that's a bit besides the point). Even in Japanese, the best sources I know of are quite spotty.

Now when i posted this question i assumed translated drama CD scripts was on the same level as anime episode scripts such as the ones i posted in [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22141/in-code-geass-r2-episode-17-why-did-lelouch-lie-to-suzaku-about-what-he-ordered/22150#22150) from [Anime Transcripts](http://animetranscripts.wikispaces.com/) (and no doubt other places).

So i am wondering should links to scripts (whether they be from a Soundtracks or Anime) be classed as "pirated versions of copyright materials" and thus treated in the same way as links to illegal anime streaming/downloading sites? if not all Scripts which ones should be classified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scripts are definitely part of the copyright of a work. Translated scripts are a little bit harder to pin down, because [copyright applies to an expression of an idea, rather than the idea itself](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/13050005/ns/business-cnbc_tv/t/hollywoods-new-piracy-problem-stolen-scripts/).

In saying that, a site that provides transcripts of the script isn't necessarily illegal - if it has gotten permission from the rights holders. I don't believe any such site currently exists though, so we can probably blanket treat them as illegal sources.

Snippets of scripts probably come under fair use and it is okay to quote them, or link to a source that has an extract. The rules are undefined and fuzzy about length - but if you're not obviously taking too much, it's probably fine.

I think we should avoid linking these sites, but allow snippets to be quoted - giving the benefit of doubt to those who may have transcribed it from source for the answers.

(IANAL.)

Comment: I agree with this answer. It should be noted that whether or not you're a lawyer has little to do with our policy. Our policy isn't intended to enforce compliance with any particular copyright law, and copyright claims are handled by SE's legal team (which is unrelated to community moderation). The intent of our community moderation policies toward such questions is more as a show of goodwill towards the original creators of the content and to try to avoid certain classes of undesirable questions.

Comment: Yep, but just in case anyone was taking this advice on a personal level